# Site Collection 403 forbidden

Tags: 2013, site-collection, central-administration, content-database, 403

I created a new SP2013 Web application and I **mounted two old content DB**.
Now I am getting **error 403** while opening some sites from the browser.
Sites were working fine, there are no locks and I am using a site collection administrator user.

Where is the problem?

Comment: Did you add the new web application URL to your DNS? How did you mount the content databases? Did you create a new root site collection in the new web application?

Comment: I used mount-spcontentdatabase. Some site collection are working others no (same content db!!)

Comment: You could try to reset yourself as site collection administrator. This has worked for me before. Or you could use powershell to loop the sitecollections to make sure that you are site collection administrator: $w = Get-SPWebApplication 'http//webappurl'
Get-SPSite -WebApplication $w -limit all | Select-Object url, owner, SecondaryContact

Comment: I checked, I am site collection admin (also reset it) but still not working. It works if I add my user under user policy for the web application. (full control). But I do not want that!

Comment: Are any users able to reach the sites?

Comment: none. I tried different users but no luck

Comment: did you configure the Object cache on the web application?

Comment: I do not. Is it needed?

Comment: for publishing site yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The application pool acoount had no permission on the DB.
Adding the permission solved my problem.